# Freemarker: Combining macros and functions

Tags: freemarker

For a specific use case, I need the functionality of a function that can also write output. I can't use macros because my functions return values. Is there a possibility that either functions generate outputs or macros return values? Or are there perhaps other possibilities to generate such a functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. It's either a return value, or writing to the output. The closest is to write a macro, and then also set a variable in it with `#assign` or `#global`. And then you can establish a convention that it always assigns to the variable called `result`.

There's yet another possibility, which probably not ideal for you. Macro calls can have nested content, to which they can pass a values (kind of look variables). So then you could do something like `<@myMacro ; it><#assign myResult = it></@>`.